# How to cancel multiple delayed performSelector calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have to stop the call in the fenumeration.

```
NSTimeInterval delay = 2;
for (NSString* sentence in sentences) {
   [sentenceHandler performSelector:@selector(parseSentence:)
                         withObject:sentence
                         afterDelay:delay];
   delay += 2;
}
```

How to stop this call from above? I tried:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:sentenceHandler 
    selector:@selector(parseSentence) object:nil];
```

but there's no effect? Does it only quit one of the many calls in the loop?

Answer (score 13):

You have two options. You could use this which would remove all queued calls to `parseSentence:`:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:sentenceHandler];
```

Or you can remove each one individually (Note the colon ":" after the method `parseSentence`):

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:sentenceHandler
                                         selector:@selector(parseSentence:)
                                           object:sentence];
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried out the [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:sentenceHandler; but I does not work

Comment: Try the second one. Note that you need to send the original sentence to the `object:` parameter, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: I really would like to do so, but I don´t know how to get those objects (sentences) after they have been used in the fast enumeration. Do I have to put all of them in a collection in order to iterate through while calling cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:... ?

Comment: Ok I tried it now by iterating through the same array I´m using when performing the calls I want to stop (Array sentences.. see entry post). I´m using all of those same objects but I still shows no effect. What is wrong with that??

Answer (score 1):

Try `@selector(parseSentence:)` instead of `@selector(parseSentence)`. The two are not equivalent. Also, you have to specify the `object:`. The documentation clearly says you can't pass `nil` if you haven't passed `nil` in the original `performSelector:...` call.

Comment: Oh, I didn´t use copy paste. I set the colon. I guess it´s hardly possible to get the object.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, ensuring the string was identical in the `performSelector` and the `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where I was unaware that I was scheduling multiple performSelector calls on different objects so the "self" was different in each case.

I'd recommend throwing in a **NSLog(@"Self: %@",self); before** each of your bits of code such as:

```
for (NSString* sentence in sentences) {
    NSLog(@"Self: %@",self);
   [sentenceHandler performSelector:@selector(parseSentence:)
                         withObject:sentence
                         afterDelay:delay];
   delay += 2;
}
```

Then cancel with:

```
NSLog(@"Self: %@",self);
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:sentenceHandler 
    selector:@selector(parseSentence) object:nil];
```

This will allow you to ensure you are queuing-up and releasing the selector on the right SELF.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don´t see a difference in this approach compared to others in this thread, except the fact that the calling object is (ns)logged